# Подскажите подходящее ПО или технологию

Tags: проектирование, мобильные-приложения, блок-схема, технологии

Разрабатывал приложение Android и оно уже довольно сильно раздалось. Я хочу составить схему экранов и переходов между ними (группы экранов [Activities]; и экраны внутри группы [Fragments]).
Есть переиспользуемые экраны.
Какой инструмент/технология (типо UML) мне могут облегчить задачу?

Comment: Мне нужно что-то схематичное, а не дизайнерское (типа figma/sketch)

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://vc.ru/design/138981-14-populyarnyh-programm-dlya-sozdaniya-animacii-prototipirovaniya-i-dizayna-interfeysov)